# Position relative container white space

Tags: html, css

[image: Position Relative Container]

[CSS]

```
#banner-container {
    display: block;

    margin-bottom: -55px;
    left: 0px;

    width: 100%;
    height: 55px;

    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 200;

    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;

    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

I went through all I found on here for white space, and how to remove white space from position relative containers, but I can't seem to get it. - Can someone help me get this right and explain to me why this happens?

Thanks :)

Comment: share both html and css code in fiddle

Comment: I don't have anything else, except a div with an ID banner-container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default all the elements in HTML has its own style, so does relatively placed div. IF you are using div then apply this to your css

div{margin:0px; padding:0px;}

or

*{margin:0px; padding:0px;}

this will be applied to all the elements in html

Answer (score 1):

browser have there own css styler.. u have to use

```
*
{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

or reset.css to reset the stylesheet rendered by browsers

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css

Comment: Yup just found that body had some type of padding.

Answer (score 1):

Fix:

```
body {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just enter

```
 body {
    margin:0;
    top:0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

*{margin:0;padding:0;}
else
body{margin:0;padding:0;}
else try same think in your div.